# How to align an item to the bottom of a list?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make an item go to the bottom of a list. I've tried using `Expanded` with a child of `SizedBox`. I've also tried the `Align` widget. It works with a Column, but not if the parent is a `SingleChildScrollView`.

What it should look like:

[image: what it should look like]

What it does look like:

[image]

Code (what it does look like):

```dart
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFE9E9E9),
      body: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 16),
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
            ),
            child: _SettingsList(tournamentId: tournamentId),
          ),
          Expanded(child: const SizedBox()),
          Align(
            alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
            child: buildDeleteTournamentButton(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: You can wrap it in a `Container` and set its `margin` property to `EdgeInsets.only(top: 60)`.

Or use a `Column` wrapped in `SingleChildScrollView` instead of a `ListView` if the data is static and not brought from an API.

Comment: Like I said, a  `Column` wrapped in a `SingleChildScrollView` doesn't work. It just makes the whole screen blank.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that part. the issue is SingleChildScrollView have to know the vertical size. 
Try setting the mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min for instance. and using Flexible instead of Expanded with fit of FlexFit.loose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using the `Expanded` or `Align` widget as a child of the list view so it tries to put the widget directly below the other ones. To achieve the first design I would recommend one of this two ways:

1. Replace your `ListView` with a `Stack` and use `Align` to align your "Delete tournament"-Widget at the bottom.
2. Replace your `ListView` with a `Column` and wrap the `Container` in an `Expanded`. Place your "Delete tournament"-Widget as the second child of the `Column`.

I really hope I could help.

Comment: I need it to scroll.

Comment: What should be scrollable - the entire body or the _SettingList?

Comment: The entire body.